# $\iint_D (x^2+y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$ by definition

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

Calculate $$\iint_D (x^2+y)\mathrm dx\mathrm dy$$ where $D = \{(x,y)\mid -2 \le x \le 4,\ 5x-1 \le y \le 5x+3\}$ by definition.

---

Plotting the set $D$, we notice that it is a parallelogram. I tried to divide it into equal parallelograms, i.e. take $x_i = -2 + \frac{6i}{n}$ and $y_j = 5x - 1+ \frac{4j}{m}$. The definition requires to calculate the sum $$\sigma = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^m f(\xi_i, \eta_j)\mu(D_{ij})$$
I was thinking about choosing $\xi_i = x_i$ and $\eta_j = y_j(x_i)$. However, this seems a bit strange. Also, finding the area of $D_{ij}$ doesn't seem to be convenient.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setup is fine. Notation-wise, your $\eta_j$ must be $\eta_{i,j}$ since it depends on both $i$ and $j$.

Having fixed that, you could directly compute the area of each sub-parallelogram, which would be the safer bet since it would ensure that they actually are all the same. Or you could take for granted that they are the same and just divide the total area by $mn$. Here the area is $6 \cdot 4=24$ so the area of each sub-parallelogram is $24/mn$.

Assuming that your setup is correct, that leaves you to look at

$$\frac{24}{mn} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m (-2+6i/n)^2 + 5(-2+6i/n)-1+4j/m$$

which is pretty straightforward, you just need the leading order asymptotics of $\sum_{i=1}^n i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$.

Comment: Thank you. I have calculated the sum and the limit seems to be $-150$. Strange, could you help me verify it, please?

Comment: @NodeJS If it helps in validation, I get a final answer of $240$ for the integral by another method (using change of variable).

Comment: @MathLover Yes, the calculator also gives $240$. Ok, let me try the summation again to see where I was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @MathLover What kind of change of variables did you do?

Comment: @NodeJS If you're just doing it by the usual antiderivative machinery, there's no real need for a change of variable since one of the sides of the parallelogram is parallel to one of the axes. (The Jacobian is a bit handy to validate that indeed the area of the whole parallelogram is 24 though.)

Comment: @NodeJS I used change of variable $u = 5x-y, v = x$ and it is easy to see Jacobian is $1$. Just a bit handy otherwise as Ian said, if you integrate in the order $dy$ and then $dx$ it is anyway just one integral with limits as given in the question.

Comment: I found where I was wrong while calculating the sum. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can integrate directly using Fubini's Theorem: $$\int_D f(x,y) dx dy=\int_{D_x}\bigg(\int_{D_y}f(x,y)dy\bigg)dx=\int_{D_y}\bigg(\int_{D_x}f(x,y)dx\bigg)dy$$

Where $D_x$ and $D_y$ represent the constraints on $x$ and $y$.

In this case: $$\iint_D (3-2x)(4y+5)dxdy=\int_{-2}^4\bigg(\int_{5x-1}^{5x+3}(3-2x)(4y+5)dy\bigg)dx\\=\int_{-2}^4(3-2x)\bigg(\int_{5x-1}^{5x+3}(4y+5)dy\bigg)dx$$

which is straightforward to evaluate by treating $x$ as a constant when integrating $dy$, and vice versa.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I wrote another function by a mistake. The exercise requires to calculate by definition.